# vector space axioms imply this?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the vector space axiom
$$ r(sv)=(rs)v$$

It is compatibility of scalar multiplication with field multiplication. Here $v$ is a vector in a finite dimensional vector space over a field $F$ and $r,s$ are elements in $F$. Sometimes the definition of a vector space is stated without this axiom. My question is: is it a consequence of the other axioms? Or is a definition without it a mistake?

Comment: I guess that a definition without this axiom is wrong, because I don't see how it could be deduced from the others. But I have no explicit example either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is most probably an error. A field action implies some things about the group addition in the vector space and some axioms can be removed, but not this one.

For a complete discussion of vector spaces axioms, see this paper

> [Independent Axioms for Vector Spaces](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3615171),
>   J. F. Rigby and James Wiegold.
>   *The Mathematical Gazette*
>   Vol. 57, No. 399 (Feb., 1973), pp. 56-62.

The first page is freely available and contains all you need, except the proofs. The main point is that the axioms below suffice and are independent, and so form a minimal set:

[image]

Comment: Those axioms do _not_ suffice, since they don't rule out $\: V = \{\hspace{-0.02 in}\} \;$. $\;\;\;\;$ On the other hand, I suspect that $\hspace{.19 in}$ replacing #5 with "$\hspace{.02 in}\mathbf{0} \: = \: 0\hspace{-0.03 in}\cdot \hspace{-0.03 in}a \;\;$ for all $a$ in $V\hspace{.03 in}$" would suffice. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer, I think they implicitly assume that $V$ is not empty.