# What choice of morphisms on the category of ordinals yields Hessenberg arithmetic?

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, ordinals

As discussed in the comments under [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/853698/76284):

What choice of morphisms on the category of ordinals yields [Hessenberg arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Natural_operations), i.e. the Hessenberg sum as the categorical coproduct and the Hessenberg product as the categorical product?

Furthermore, if the morphisms are order-preserving maps, do coproducts or products exist?

Comment: The latter question is very easy to answer by looking at small finite ordinals.

Answer (score 1):

The ordinals under Hessenberg arithmetic are the free commutative semiring on ordinals of the form $\omega^{\omega^\alpha}$ - any ordinal can be written in Cantor normal form as a sum of powers of $\omega$, then write those powers in Cantor normal form, and rewrite $\omega^{\omega^\alpha+\omega^\beta} \to \omega^{\omega^\alpha}\omega^{\omega^\beta}$ to get a sum of products of powers of powers of $\omega$.

So, take the free distributive category with objects $\omega^{\omega^\alpha}$. The commutative semiring of (isomorphism classes of) objects of this category, with coproduct as addition and product as multiplication (this is a commutative semiring because the category is distributive), is isomorphic to the free commutative semiring on $\omega^{\omega^\alpha}$, which (by the first paragraph) is isomorphic to the commutative semiring of ordinals with Hessenberg arithmetic, so this is the category of ordinals we're looking for.