# Proving commutativity of addition of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need to prove $(-\vec{v})+\vec{v}=\vec{0}$ using only the axioms of vector space addition and multiplication, except the commutativity axiom.

I have tried using this approach $\vec{0}=\vec{v}+(-\vec{v})$ but I get stuck and can't find a way to get the $(-\vec{v})$ first.

Comment: @sahibaArora The "duplicate" uses the theorem $-1(\vec{v})=-\vec{v}$ which I can't use.

Comment: Please see [Benjamin Dickman's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2345777/266110).

Comment: @SahibaArora The proof of proposition one is using what we are trying to prove in the proof. The proof starts with $y+x$ and then just goes back to $y+x$.

Comment: @MattSamuel no it is the same link. I can't use $-\vec{v}=-1\vec{v}$, I can only use the axioms of vector space addition and multiplication. Namely, $\vec{v}-\vec{v}=0$.

Comment: @DoubleFishFire I wasn't really asking, that was an auto-comment. I'm asserting that Benjamin Dickson's answer is sufficient to answer your question. It happens when one votes to close a question as a duplicate.

Comment: @DoubleFishFire One of the axioms of vector space addition is commutativity...

Comment: @Rick I am proving commutativity and so can't use it

Comment: @DoubleFishFire Then I think you should state clearly what axioms you are allowed to use, because if you say *axioms of vector space addition* everyone will understand that you include commutativity, as this is the most common practice.