# Vector Spaces: Redundant Axiom?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, definition, axioms

**Question**

Why are the axioms for vector space independent?

More precisely $1x=x$ seems redundant...

*(I take the axioms from: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space))*

**Explanation**

One has for zero vector:
$$\lambda0+\lambda0=\lambda(0+0)=\lambda0\implies\lambda0=0$$

And for zero scalar:
$$0x+0x=(0+0)x=0x\implies0x=0$$

In familiar form:
$$\lambda x=0\implies\lambda=0\lor x=0$$

Threrefore one calculates:
$$1(1x+x^{-1})=1(1x)+1(x^{-1})=(11)x+1(x^{-1})=1x+1(x^{-1})=1(x+x^{-1})=10=0$$

Hence for nontrivial field:
$$1\neq0\implies1x+x^{-1}=0\implies1x=x$$

But where is the flaw in that check??

Comment: I'm guessing you're using [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) axioms?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saying two axioms are "independent"?

Comment: @GregoryGrant I'm assuming what he means to ask is if we get $1v = v$ for free from the other axioms.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: Oh that may be wrong phrasing. I mean it follows from the others.

Comment: What is $x^{-1}$?  In a vector space we do not necessarily have multiplicative inverses.  Do you mean $-x$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant $x^{-1}$ is (bad) notation for $-x$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Ah got it, yes that is bad.

Comment: While there are many ways to axiomatize the notion of vector spaces, I have never seen $\lambda x=0\implies \lambda =0\lor x=0$ listed as an axiom of vectorr spaces. - By the way, you need only a single axiom: A vector pace $V$ over a field $F$ is an abelian group on which $F$ acts as uintary ring.

Comment: We're actually using $1a=a$ to deduce $0a=0$. @Freeze_S

Comment: @CameronWilliams: I especially chose this notation to be careful not assuming unproven identities like $-x=(-1)x$.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin: I didn't assume neither $1a=a$ nor $0a=a$.

Comment: @Freeze_S $-x$ is the *notation* used for the inverse in an abelaian group where the group operation is symbolized by $+$.

Comment: I suspect that your first property ($0\lambda = 0$) is actually using the fact that $1\lambda = \lambda$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Yes I know this is common notation but it may tempt to abuse $(-1)x=-x$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I don't think he did, it's true in an abelian group that $a+b=a+c$ $\Rightarrow$ $b=c$.  Where did he use $1\lambda=\lambda$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant Ah I'm mistaken. Mike has the right solution.

Comment: The listed axiom are *not* independent: indeed, commutativity of addition is a consequence of the other axioms.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/479005/589.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The axiom system you quote does not have
$$\lambda x=0\implies \lambda=0 \lor x=0 $$
as an axiom.

If we drop the axiom $1v=v$, the following becomes an example of a "vector space" over $\mathbb R$:

- $V=(\mathbb R,+)$, $F=(\mathbb R,+,\cdot)$
- for $\lambda \in F$ and $v\in V$ let $\lambda v=0$.

We do not want this to happen.

Comment: I think you may have nailed it.

Comment: But I didn't assume this, I prove it!

Comment: @Freeze_S As your "proof" would be applicable to my counterexample, it must be wrong. Do you see where?

Comment: Hmm yes that is what I actually need your help to find a flaw...

Comment: @GregoryGrant Sometimes a simpe counterexample is simpler than a seventeen comment discussion :)

Comment: @Freeze_S Simple. To conclude from $\lambda0=0$ and $0x=0$ that $\lambda x=0\implies \lambda=0\lor x=0$ is a non-sequitur. For example in the ring $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ we have $\lambda 0=0$ and $0x=0$ for all $\lambda, x$, but $\lambda x=0\not\implies \lambda=0\lor x=0$ because $\lambda=x=2+4\mathbb Z$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @Freeze_S You did not prove $\lambda x=0\implies \lambda=0$ or $x=0$. You proved the other implication.

Comment: @Freeze_S You showed $\lambda0=0$ and $0x=0$, you did not show $\lambda x=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\lambda=0$ or $x=0$.

Comment: Aaaaahh thanks yes that was the flaw. :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Why don't we "want" such a thing to happen as in your answer?

Answer (score 24):

A mistake: You only showed that $\lambda=0$ or $x=0$ $\implies$ $\lambda x=0$.
You did not show the reverse implication: $\lambda x=0 \implies \lambda=0$ or $x=0$. A proof of that implication uses the axiom $1x=x$.

A standard counterexample of a structure that satisfies all the other axioms save $1x=x$ is the following:

- $V=\Bbb{F}^2$
- $(x_1,x_2)+(y_1,y_2)=(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2)$, i.e. the usual componentwise vector addition
- $a*(x_1,x_2)=(ax_1,0)$.

The system $(V,+,*)$ satisfies all the other axioms but $1x=x$. Note that that reverse implication does not hold in this system:
$$1*(0,1)=(0,0)=0_V.$$

Answer (score 18):

In order to prove
$$
\lambda x=0\implies \lambda=0\vee x=0\tag1
$$
you need to use the axiom $1x=x$.

Here is how you prove (1): if $\lambda\neq0$, then $\lambda x=0$ implies
$$
\lambda^{-1}(\lambda x)=\lambda^{-1}(0)
$$

$$
(\lambda^{-1}\lambda)x=
0
$$
$$
1x
=0
$$
$$x=0$$
so $\lambda\neq0$ implies $x=0$, or equivalently, $\lambda=0\vee x=0$.

Thus, your proof of the axiom $1x=x$ being redundant goes in circles.

Answer (score 8):

The axioms of the list you cite are not independent, but $1x=x$ is not the problem.

Commutativity of addition follows from the other axioms; let $x,y\in V$ and set
$$
z=(1+1)(x+y)
$$
Then
$$
z=1(x+y)+1(x+y)=x+y+x+y
$$
(parentheses can be omitted because of associativity). On the other hand
$$
z=(1+1)x+(1+1)y=1x+1x+1y+1y=x+x+y+y
$$
Therefore, being $V,+$ a group, we can do
$$
(-x)+x+y+x+y+(-y)=(-x)+x+x+y+y+(-y)
$$
which gives
$$
y+x=x+y
$$

---

An correct objection would be that, removing the commutativity of addition axiom, only right zero and right opposites are assumed. However a general result about monoids applies.

> Let $M$ be a (multiplicative) semigroup, with right identity $e$. If every element has a right $e$-inverse, then every element has a left $e$-inverse and the right identity $e$ is also a left identity.

The assumption is that $ae=a$, for all $a\in M$, and that, for all $a\in M$, there exists $b\in M$ such that $ab=e$.

Let $a\in M$ and $b\in M$ such that $ab=e$. Then $bab=be=b$, so, if $c\in M$ and $bc=e$, we have $babc=bc$, hence $ba=e$. Moreover, $ea=aba=a$. Thus $e$ is also a left identity and $b$ a left inverse of $a$.

Comment: The commutativity axiom is indeed redundant, but your proof is incomplete. The list only postulates the existence of right zero and right inverses, not left zero or left inverses, so you need to prove those.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Done.