# About the axioms for vector spaces. Can we derive the axiom which guarantees the existence of the zero vector from these $7$ axioms?

Tags: vector-spaces, axioms

I am reading an applied mathematics book (in Japanese) by Kenichi Kanatani.

The author wrote as follows:

> If non-empty set $\mathcal{L}$ along with an addition on $\mathcal{L}$ and a scalar multiplication on $\mathcal{L}$ has the following properties, then $\mathcal{L}$ is called a vector space.
>
> 1. For any $u,v\in\mathcal{L}$, $u+v=v+u$.
> 2. For any $u,v,w\in\mathcal{L}$, $u+(v+w)=(u+v)+w$.
> 3. For any $u,v\in\mathcal{L}$, there exists $x\in\mathcal{L}$ such that $u+x=v$. (We write $x$ as $v-u$.)
> 4. For any $u,v\in\mathcal{L}$ and any $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, $\lambda(u+v)=\lambda v+\lambda u$.
> 5. For any $u\in\mathcal{L}$ and any $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}$, $(\lambda+\mu)u=\lambda u + \mu u$.
> 6. For any $u\in\mathcal{L}$ and any $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R}$, $(\lambda\mu)u=\lambda(\mu u)$.
> 7. For any $u\in\mathcal{L}$, $1u=u$.

And the author wrote as follows:

> For any $u\in\mathcal{L}$, $u-u\in\mathcal{L}$. We write this as $0$. By definition, for any $u\in\mathcal{L}$, $u+0=u$.

By the way, the author is not a mathematician.

The author wrote "For any $u,v\in\mathcal{L}$, there exists $x\in\mathcal{L}$ such that $u+x=v$. (We write $x$ as $v-u$.)". But the author didn't prove that $x$ is unique.

The author didn't prove that for any $u,v\in\mathcal{L}$, $u-u=v-v$ held.

Can we really prove that $u-u=v-v$ for any $u,v\in\mathcal{L}$?

---

Suppose that we can prove that for any $u,v\in\mathcal{L}$, there exists $x\in\mathcal{L}$ such that $u+x=v$ **uniquely**.

Then, for any $u,v\in\mathcal{L}$, $$u+v+0u=(u+0u)+v=(1u+0u)+v=(1+0)u+v=1u+v=u+v,$$
and $$u+v+0v=u+(v+0v)=u+(1v+0v)=u+(1+0)v=u+1v=u+v.$$
So, **by uniqueness**, $$0u=0v.$$
Let $z$ be an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{L}$.
Let $u$ be an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{L}$.
Then, $$u+0z=u+0u=1u+0u=(1+0)u=1u=u.$$
So, $0z$ is zero vector.

Comment: Good observation! I guess the way to prove it would be to first show that $u-v=u+(-1)v$, which shows that $u-u=0u$ and $v-v=0v$, and then use the various scalar-multiplication properties to show that $0u=0v$.

Comment: @tchappy ha, you may begin with the assumption $x=u-u$ and $y=v-v$ as well. Think about the consequences of what if $x≠y$ - are they in contradiction with properties (1) to (7).

Comment: @GregMartin Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @AweKumarJha Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2378914/589. It seems that $0u=0v$ is a requirement.

Comment: @lhf Thank you very much for your information.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v$ be an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{L}$.
Let $u$ be an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{L}$.
There exists $x\in\mathcal{L}$ such that $u+x=v$.
$v+0u=(u+x)+0u=(u+0u)+x=(1u+0u)+x=(1+0)u+x=1u+x=u+x=v$.
So, $0u$ is zero vector.