# The uniqueness of the identity elements are a request in field axioms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I'm studying analysis and notice a conflict when some authors write about them. Sometimes is uniqueness of the neutral elements are in the axioms, sometimes is a corollary of the axioms which talk about neutral elements of $ + $ and $*$.

Are the uniqueness part of axioms or not?

Comment: By uniqueness, you mean the axiom that $0\neq 1$?  If the multiplicative identity is the same as the additive identity, we would get that $0=1$ and so $0 = 0\cdot x 
 = 1\cdot x = x$ implying $x=0$ for all $x$ and so there is only one element in the field.  Some authors will specifically avoid calling the field of one element a "field" in order to make phrasing theorems and other results easier so as to not have to continually write and put disclaimers like "*except for the trivial field*" on everything.

Comment: Please list the texts you know of which A) include the uniqueness as axioms, and B) Derive the uniqueness from other axioms.

Comment: This really depends on the philosophy of the author. Some prefer that axioms be as minimalist as possible, including no more than the minimum necessary requirements to define a field, so they derive uniqueness of the identities as corollaries to the definition. Others probably want to avoid unnecessary arguments and include the uniqueness in the definition.  I always preferred to derive uniqueness. It's an opportunity to see some general arguments in a concrete situation as shown in the answers. Uniqueness of negative and multiplicative inverse offer the same opportunity.

Comment: One is free to include redundant axioms if one so desires (a common example is [commutativity of addition in rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/702626/242)). Search on "redundant axiom" for many more examples. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/891446/242) for some ways to *discover* such uniqueness proofs

Answer (score 1):

Identity elements are unique for any binary operation:

Suppose $e,e'$ are both identity elements for our operation $*$. Then $e=e*e'=e'$.

Thus, there is no need for uniqueness to be a part of your axioms.

Comment: I understand, Thank u

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $e_1$ and $e_2$ are both identity elements of $(S, \circ)$.

Then by the definition of identity element:
$$\forall s \in S: s \circ e_1 = s = e_2 \circ s$$

Then:
$$e_1 = e_2 \circ e_1 = e_2$$

So:
$$e_1 = e_2$$
and there is only one identity element after all.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).