# Is the "commutativity of addition" axiom in a field redundant?

Tags: field-theory, axioms

I have seen an assertion that the "commutativity of addition" axiom in a field is redundant because it can be proved from the other axioms.  There are relevant posts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702616/in-a-commutative-ring-is-addition-necessarily-commutative) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994041/whats-wrong-with-this-proof-that-commutativity-is-implied-by-the-other-field-ax).

**However**, both of these proofs use the two cancellation laws
$$a+c=b+c\ \Rightarrow\ a=b\qquad\hbox{and}\qquad c+a=c+b\ \Rightarrow\ a=b\ .$$
In my source, cancellation is not specifically mentioned, and only the **one-sided** identity and negative axioms are assumed:
$$a+0=a\qquad\hbox{and}\qquad a+(-a)=0\ .$$
Can commutativity of addition be proved with these axioms (and the other usual field axioms)?  Or is it an oversight on the part of the author?

To be completely clear: it is not assumed that $0+a=a$, nor that $(-a)+a=0$.

The source is Howard Eves, *Great Moments in Mathematics after 1650*, chapter 28.

Comment: Can you add to your question the exact list of axioms you're working with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these are sufficient assumptions. $0$ is also a left additive identity. Indeed, let $a\in F$, and denote $b=0+a$. Then:

$b+(-a)=(0+a)+(-a)=0+(a+(-a))=0+0=0=a+(-a) \ \ \ \ (*)$

The element $-a$ also has a right additive inverse. To simplify notation, denote $c=-(-a)$. Then adding $c$ to both sides of $(*)$ from the right gives $b=a$, as desired.

Similarly, it can be proved that $(-a)+a=0$ for any $a\in F$. Indeed, let $b=(-a)+a$. Then:

$b+(-a)=((-a)+a)+(-a)=(-a)+(a+(-a))=(-a)+0=-a=0+(-a)$

In the last step we use the fact that we already know that $0$ is a two sided additive identity. And again, adding $c=-(-a)$ to both sides from the right gives $b=0$, i.e $(-a)+a=0$.

Note that we never used multiplication here. This proof shows that the axioms of a group can be replaced by only having a left (or right) identity, and a left (respectively right) inverse for each element.