# In a ring, if addition is commutative, does it implies that multiplication is commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This might be a silly question after all. But I guess that assuming associativity and commutativity for $+$ in a ring, one could reorder the operations and obtain the commutativity for $\cdot$.

Comment: No. Matrices. ;;

Comment: Dear Jesus:  I am disappointed; I thought Jesus Christ knew all such things!  In any event, consider Aloizio Macedo's comment!  Barachot!

Comment: @RobertLewis No. See my profile for explanation.

Comment: NIce!  I always had faith that Jesus uses a flat-screen monitor, and dresses for business!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the answer is no. Matrix multiplication is not commutative while matrix addition is, for instance.

Further, I've never come across a ring where the addition was not commutative. It is inbuilt in the definition I know of rings. In part this might be because having a $1$ forces addition to be commutative, and typically we investigate rings (not rngs). This is talked about more in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609364/why-is-ring-addition-commutative).

Comment: Of, it seems I confused one thing. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/zLZroXB.jpg). He says: *"In addition, if $ab=ba$, then it is a commutative ring"*. I thought he was talking about addition. Silly me.

Comment: It's not every day I get to leave a comment for @JesusChrist, so I'll try to make it good. A ring, by definition, includes commutativity of addition. If a ring is labelled as commutative or non-commutative, it is referring the multiplication operation.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $(x+y)+(x+y) = 2(x+y) = 2x + 2y = x+x+y+y$, whence you get that $x+y=y+x$ i.e. addition is *always* commutative in a ring.