# Is there a name for a non-abelian group which is also a monoid?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

A ring is usually defined to be an abelian group under addition and a monoid under multiplication.

I wondered whether there is a name for some structure that is simply a (not necessarily abelian) group under some binary operation and a monoid under multiplication.

Is there a name for this? If not, why not?

EDIT: As a response to the comments, I want to add my motivation for the question. Indeed, I do not have a specific example in mind. I asked because I observed that the structure of non-abelian Groups or Rings is much richer than the structure of abelian ones and thus thought there might be a rich world of non-commutative rings with non-commutative addition. And I don't know all the history of mathematics, so I thought maybe someone already researched about this in a deeper way and brought up many examples I could not have thought of. Conversely, there could be a reason why those structures have not been studied yet, e.g. because due to some effect it is algebraically difficult to construct such a thing etc.

Comment: Do you have common or useful examples of such a thing?  If not, that might explain why there's no terminology.

Comment: Do you have any particular case of interest in mind? All well-known algebraic structures that I can think of are additive under addition. (rings, modules/vector spaces, etc.) Why should we define something that is not interesting in mathematics?

Comment: Nearly everything that one can define has some interesting structure. I mean take a group, there are extremely many that are interesting and non-abelian. So it is quite natural to ask whether there are groups that are also monoids but not abelian.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609364/why-is-ring-addition-commutative In particular there’s a link there to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-ring It appears the distributive property needs to be adjusted to make this work.

Comment: Take a non-abelian group and define an additional operation $\odot$ by $a \odot b=e$ for all $a, b$ in the group (where $e$ is the identity).  Done.  So what?

Comment: Thanks for the link. So indeed it is not a stupid question @Randall

Comment: @Randall, your example might not be interesting but obviously there are many more possibilities.

Comment: @exchange  Yes, it is certainly possible, but I would actually like to see some interesting examples (and I don't think your question is dumb).

Comment: @Randall, ok I understand. I added a comment to explain why I asked.

Comment: To be fair, there is a name for this sort of thing in any setting.  They're roughly called "monoid objects in a category."  You're asking about monoid objects in the category of groups, I suppose.  (This definition might also force distribution, depending on the category, which you may not want.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_(category_theory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common thing like this is the [near-ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-ring).

I think this question is totally a duplicate of [Why is ring addition commutative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/609364/29335) but I am reluctant to hammer it.