# Nilpotent ring example

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have recently learned about nilpotency in a group/ring.I am thinking about doing some work on a non-commutative nilpotent ring but i could not find an example. More precisely, (S,+,.) is nilpotent, where S is nilpotent w.r.t. both of it's operation.

Comment: "nilpotent w.r.t. both operations" does not make any sense.  "nilpotent" is defined in terms of repeated multiplication resulting in the additive identity. What would "additively nilpotent" mean? Repeated addition resulting in ...?  If you again said "additive identity" then that isn't nilpotency at all, that's just an element of finite order in the additive group.

Comment: I said it in a sense that everytime we see a set with two algebraic structure, it amuses me that always one of them is commutative..i just thought what would happen if someone takes both operation noncommutative??? If you know something, please tell me, as i couldn't get any answer from anyone. Everyone 
is just saying that it for definition. But why is it in the definition if it doesn't need to be there.

Comment: [there is already a question addressing this for rings](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/609364/29335)  As for other structures, I am not sure, but in all likelihood it is just because it is sufficient to suit most useful applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a set of matrices $n\times n$, $n>3$ such that $\{a_{1n-2},a_{1n-1},a_1n,a_{2n-1},a_{2n},a_{3n}\}\subset\mathbb R$ and $a_{ij}=0$ for any $(i,j)\not\in\{(1,n-2),(1,n-1),(1,n),(2,n-1),(2,n),(3,n)\}.$

Comment: But it's commutative under addition. I have asked about nilpotency in both operations.

Comment: @Aninda Chakraborty It must be commutative with $+$ because it's a ring.

Comment: Although i don't think it's nilpotent as you can take a_(1,1)=2 and 0 otherwise, then it's not of a finite order.

Comment: Also, why it is necessary to be commutative of atleast one operation, i don't understand that.

Comment: @AnindaChakraborty That is because of the definition of a ring.

Comment: Though i have asked a different question(an example of a nilpotent ring) but it concerns me that if the commutativity is only for the sake of definition or it is actually needed for compatibility of these two operations.

Comment: @Aninda Chakraborty You need associativity for $\cdot$ because otherwise, we not exactly know what is it $S^n$. By the way, antiassociativity of $\cdot$ gives a nilpotent ring: just $S^4=0$. Here $S$ is a ring with a property: $a+a=0\Rightarrow a=0.$

Comment: No, i'm not talking about this particular question. In general why do we need commutativity of addition in the definition of a ring. And thanks for your example, it's so elementary and beautiful.

Comment: @Aninda Chakraborty By the definition of a ring. Otherwise, it's not a ring. You are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Start with a field of $3$ elements $F_3$ and take the free algebra $F_3\langle x,y\rangle$ in noncommuting indeterminates, then take the quotient by $(x,y)^3$, and let $R$ be the ideal $(x,y)/(x,y)^3$ in the quotient ring.

It's nilpotent because $a^3=0$ for everything in the ring, and it's not commutative because $xy\neq yx$.

It also satisfies $3a=0$ for every $a\in R$, if that is what you meant by "additively nilpotent" (it should actually just be said that everything has additive order less than $3$.)

Comment: Wonderful !!! But please read my comment answer answer my doubt also. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @rschwieb  Is your ring  nilpotent of order six?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg By definition, if $r,s,t\in (x,y)$, then $rst\in (x,y)^3$.  In particular $r^3\in (x,y)^3$. So, nilpotent of order $3$.

Comment: Maybe it's nil of order three?

Comment: And if it's a nil ring of order three, so it's a nilpotent ring of order six by the Nagata-Higman's theorem. What do you think? Thank you! By the way, by this theorem it should be seventh order, but we can prove that an order six is enough.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg you have me at a disadvantage since I have no idea what you are talking about.  I interpreted the question as asking for an example where $R^n=\{0\}$ for a noncommutative ring.  That is my educated guess based on the user’s information.  You may have some other definition in mind.

Comment: @rschwieb $R^n=\{0\}$ it says that any words as $a_1a_2...a_n$ are equal to $0$. This ring named a nilpotent ring. In your example we have a ring with identity $a^3=0$ for any $a\in R$. This ring named a nil ring.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg No nonzero nil ring has an identity. As i mentioned, this ring *by construction* satisfies $R^3=\{0\}$.   I am not following what objection you have.

Comment: @rschwieb Your first statement it's just wrong. A nil ring of the limited order  has identity by the definition of this ring. From your second statement I see now what did you mean. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg The identity is an idempotent element. How do you propose to have a nonzero idempotent nilpotent element?

Comment: @rschwieb It's another problem already.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I’m unsure if that means you now understand my comment about the identity is correct...

Comment: @rschwieb It's just another problem. We have a nil ring with identity $a^3=0$.For all associative ring $R$ with this identity we have $R^6=\{0\}$. (also we need if $6a=0$ so $a=0$).

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg well, I agree that logical inconsistency is a problem (that’s what the conditions of a nonzero nilpotent idempotent produce: a contradiction)