# Example of a nilpotent division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Actually, my headline pretty much sums up my question. I have done some exercises on nilpotent group and I'm thinking about an example of a division ring $(D,+,\cdot )$ where $(D,+)$ is an abelian group and $(D\setminus 0,\cdot)$ is a nilpotent group.

Answer (score 2):

If $x$ is a nilpotent element that is also a unit, then it is $0$.

This means that no nilpotent ring can have any nonzero invertible elements.

A division ring has at least its identity as a nonzero invertible element.

So no, there isn't any such ring.

---

*Update*

The user has since updated their question to indicate they are using a homemade definition of "nilpotent ring" that is not consistent with the standard notion I was using.  The following is added after that came to light.

After doing a little research I came across this interesting survey:

> [Hazrat, Roozbeh, M. Mahdavi-Hezavehi, and Mehran Motiee. "Multiplicative groups of division rings." Mathematical Proceedings of the Royal Irish Academy. Vol. 114. No. 1. Royal Irish Academy, 2014.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.0596.pdf)

In it, they mention that in 1950, Hua proved that when the multiplicative group of a division ring is solvable, the division ring is actually a field. Since nilpotent groups are solvable, this would say that all examples are actually fields.

Since finite fields are obvious examples of "nilpotent fields" in the sense you gave, I guess you were mainly interested in noncommutative examples, but the above account says that this is not possible.

Comment: But, I've read the definition of nilpotent group as the central series is finite.

Comment: @AnindaChakraborty and that has no bearing on the definition of a nilpotent ring.  Surely you already know this to the last question of yours we discussed this in? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3329144/29335

Comment: I know, but I'm seeing nilpotent division ring (D,+,•) as (D,+) is an abelian group and (D\{0},•) is a nilpotent group and I'm seeking for an example of this kind.

Comment: thanks for sharing with me this article.